# Checking if code has been modified (without opening the workbook???)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find a way to verify that no code changes have been made in a workbook that is sent to someone and then returned with the code.

I have the template workbook with the correct code that I'd be checking against.
I have not been able to find the answer as yet in my google searches

If possible, I'd like to verify the code has not been changed without opening the workbook (which seems impossible) or at least with the macros disabled.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this something that would be covered if you digitally sign the file? If it came back changed it would no longer match your signature

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your response. it appears that I don't have any certificates installed and getting them from IT will be a bit of a nightmare... Any other ideas?

Comment: What about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjwVD.png)? Kind of self certification.

Comment: Thanks @Storax. I've looked there but there are no certificates installed and I'd have to get the admins to add one which will not happen before I need to have this sent.

Comment: I am talking about something like [that](https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/25363/create-a-valid-digital-self-signed-certificate-selfcert-exe)

Comment: SORTED... thanks mate.